# My UPS gets very loud when turning on the oven

Tags: power, ups

My UPS starts making a rather loud noise (which sounds a bit like a very loud version of a fridge's motor) when I turn on the oven. It's also vibrating quite a bit when that happens.

It's the only electric appliance in the house that has this effect on the UPS. Everything else, including the water heater, doesn't affect it.

Changing to another wall socket (I've tried one that is controlled by a different safety switch and therefore should be on a different circuit) doesn't help.

Why is this happening? But more importantly, can this actually damage the UPS?

Comment: Some info that may be helpful, where is the UPS plugged in?  Near it, in line with it, on the same circuit?

Comment: @nerdwaller Question updated. Basically, it doesn't matter where I plug it in.

Comment: You need to assess some things. How old is your place? How old is the wiring? How is it wired? Is there a short in your oven? Breakers or Fuses? Does a different UPS have this issue? Is your oven GAS or electric? If gas, can you plug it into another outlet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm no electrician, but UPS's making noise is never a good thing.

If the UPS came with Powerchute or other similar monitoring software, you may try (at your own risk) having the monitoring software running with your UPS connected to your PC and look at how things change when you turn your oven on.  The software may also display any alerts from your UPS that could give you clues.

Off the top of my head, I'd say the oven is making the voltage supplied to your other outlets dip below an acceptable threshold.  The UPS may actually be kicking on and providing power, especially if you hear a click from it at the same time you turn the oven on.

Have your building's wiring examined by a competent professional.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's only a serial port cable that comes with it. My PC doesn't have that. Also, if I cut the power to the UPS so that it kicks-in, it makes no noise (other then beeping). It delivers power to the PC pretty silently. Furthermore, other stuff I have (TV and hi-fi) don't seem to be affected at all. I assume that if there was a short somewhere, it would interfere with the hi-fi and/or TV.

Comment: Well, you can get a USB-to-serial adapter if your PC doesn't have one.